# Specify multiple files for FileWatcher Autosys job

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

I would like to setup a FileWatcher job that looks for multiple signal files to be present before it kicks off. Is there any way to check for the presence of multiple files before the child job is triggered ? Or would I have to create multiple file watcher jobs, one for each file ?

Answer (score 1):

File Trigger (R11) or File watcher (legacy) jobs can only take one value in the watch_file attribute. R11 does allow for wild cards, but that is probably not what you want. I would create a separate job for each signal file, put the jobs in a box, and run the downstream job on the success of the box.